# Session gets timed out sooner than expected when using Spring Security

Tags: spring, session, spring-security, web.xml, session-timeout

I'm using Spring Security 3.1 and I'm facing a problem with session time outs.
I've set session time-out in the *web.xml* as follows:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        45
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

So session is supposed to be expired after 45 minutes.
However I've noticed that session is expired **exactly** after 2 minutes! Whether I'm working with application or not.

These are my spring security beans:

```
<bean id="ConcurrentSessionFilterAdmin" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
    <property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry"/>
    <property name="logoutHandlers">
        <list>
            <ref bean = "logoutHandler"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="expiredUrl" value="/admin/login.jsp?error=expiredURL"/>
</bean>
<bean id="sessionRegistry"
    class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" autowire="byType" />

<bean id="logoutHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler">
</bean>

<bean id="securityContextPersistenceFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter">
    <property name="securityContextRepository" ref="securityContextRepository"/>
</bean>

<bean id="securityContextRepository"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository">
    <property name="allowSessionCreation" value="false" />
</bean>
<bean id="logoutFilterAdmin"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
    <constructor-arg value="/admin/login.jsp" />
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="logoutHandler"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/admin/j_spring_security_logout"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilterAdmin"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="usernameParameter" value="j_username"/>
    <property name="passwordParameter" value="j_password"/>
    <property name="allowSessionCreation" value="false"/>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="authenticationFailureHandlerAdmin"/>
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="authenticationSuccessHandlerAdmin"/>
    <property name="continueChainBeforeSuccessfulAuthentication" value="false"/>
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/admin/j_spring_security_check"/>
    <property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sessionAuthenticationStrategy"/>
</bean>
<bean id="authenticationFailureHandlerAdmin"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/admin/login.jsp?error=loginfailed" />
</bean>
<bean id="authenticationSuccessHandlerAdmin" 
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="requestCache" ref="requestCache"/>
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/admin/index.html"/>
</bean>

<bean id="requestCache" class="org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache"/>

<bean id="sessionAuthenticationStrategy"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
    <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
    <property name="migrateSessionAttributes" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="basicAuthenticationFilterAdmin"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationDetailsSource" ref="authenticationDetailsSource"/>
    <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="authenticationEntryPoint"/>
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
</bean>
<bean id="authenticationDetailsSource"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationDetailsSourceImpl"/>
<bean id="requestCacheAwareFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter">
    <constructor-arg ref="requestCache"/>
</bean>

<bean id="securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter">
    <property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_"/>
</bean>

<bean id="anonymousAuthenticationFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter">
    <constructor-arg value="KEY"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionManagementFilterAdmin" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter">
    <constructor-arg ref="securityContextRepository"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="sessionAuthenticationStrategy"/> 
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="authenticationFailureHandlerAdmin"/>
    <property name="invalidSessionStrategy" ref="invalidSessionStrategyAdmin"/>
</bean>
<bean id="invalidSessionStrategyAdmin"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.session.SimpleRedirectInvalidSessionStrategy">
    <constructor-arg value="/admin/login.jsp"/>
    <property name="createNewSession" value="false"/>
</bean>
<bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">     
    <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="authenticationEntryPoint" />
    <property name="accessDeniedHandler" ref="accessDeniedHandler" />
    <property name="requestCache" ref="requestCache"/>
</bean>
<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint">
</bean>
<bean id="accessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl">
</bean>
 <bean id="filterSecurityInterceptorAdmin"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accessDecisionManager" />
    <property name="securityMetadataSource" ref="myFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="myFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource" class="com.datx.security.model.MyFilterSecurityMetadataSource" autowire="byName" scope="prototype">
</bean>
```

After two minutes, I'm redirected to `/admin/login.jsp?error=expiredURL` which is set in the first bean configuration. (Which means session is expired)

The question is which of these beans are responsible for session expiration? What property haven't I set that causes this problem?

Comment: I believe the problem is with *invalidSessionStrategyAdmin* bean.

Comment: Can you trying setting allowSessionCreation to true

Comment: Done that before. As the application is totally based on restful web services, if I do that [again], I'll get more troubles as for each request it creates new session and this causes "a login page per each request".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Security relies on the underlying container, i.e. it's the container who manages session timeouts(please add information about the container you're using). However, I believe that web.xml settings usually should have a bigger priority if the server is Java EE compliant.

Also individual session timeouts can be tweaked dynamically by calling [HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval%28int%29)  method, or the session can be invalidated by calling [invalidate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate%28%29).

It's possible for Spring Security to invalidate session in some cases (for example, after logging in, the user gets a new HttpSession).

Also session invalidation can be caused by Spring Security concurrent-session control mechanism, for example if the max-sessions value is specified.

You can check when Spring Security invalidates the session by setting **DEBUG** logging level for  **org.springframework.security.*** namespace, as Spring typically writes such info to the logger.

Comment: Could you explain it to me that how can I enable this DEBUG log thing. A brief hint might suffice.

Comment: See section 1.3.2 of the [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html) for example if you are using logback it will be <logger name="org.springframework.security" level="DEBUG">
  <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </logger> and   <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </layout>
  </appender> in logback xml

Comment: Surprisingly you got it right. It was concurrent-session control responsible for it as my colleague and I were logging in at the same time. Thanks, for the help.